# PILLOW doesn't work correctly on mac

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have the following code I wrote on windows 7:

```
canvas_width = 150
canvas_height = 150

brush_size = 3
color = "black"

def paint(event):
        global brush_size
        global color
        x1 = event.x - brush_size
        x2 = event.x + brush_size
        y1 = event.y - brush_size
        y2 = event.y + brush_size
        w.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2,
                      fill = color,
                      outline=color)


    def getter(widget):
        x = root.winfo_rootx() + widget.winfo_x()
        y = root.winfo_rooty() + widget.winfo_y()
        x1 = x + widget.winfo_width()
        y1 = y + widget.winfo_height()
        ImageGrab.grab().crop(x,y,x1,y1).save("img1.jpg")

    root = Tk()
    w = Canvas(root,
               width=canvas_width,
               height=canvas_height,
               bg="white")
    w.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)

    save_btn = Button(text="Save", width=10, command=getter(w))

    w.grid(row=2, column=0,
           columnspan=7,
           padx=5, pady=5,
           sticky=E+W+S+N)
    w.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
    w.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    save_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

And it works fine on windows 7.  But I ran the same code on macos Sierra and something went wrong. When I try to save the canvas, I get an image that starts from a window title bar. When I move the window to the center of screen and hit 'save' I get an image of the center of screen, not the window canvas. And when I try to save the canvas on windows 7 - I get an image of canvas no matter where I move the window. What the hell? How do I fix the code to save the canvas only? On mac?